# What Happened To Lux Bonteri?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

After *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, Lux Bonteri, son of Separatist Senator Mina Bonteri, became Senator of Onderon after joining a rebel group. What happened to him after that?

Answer (score 2):

The Wookieepedia article gives a nice synopsis of his life after The Clone Wars

> After the rise of the Galactic Empire, Bonteri married an Imperial and became a [step] father to her daughter. [...] Bonteri eventually became a member of the Rebel Alliance
> <sub>*[Lux Bonteri](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lux_Bonteri#The_Mentor)*</sub>

The last we see of him (chronologically, in current canon) is him getting shot during an imperial raid to get information his group had.

> When Iden didn’t answer, [Lux] continued, taking a cautious step toward her. “And you know…that gives me almost more hope than I had before. You can’t quit hoping, Iden. Cling to it like a lifeline, because it is. Hope that something you do, or say, will make a difference. Look at what happened with the Death Star. One man hoped, for years, clutching an awesome, tremendous secret close in his heart, that somehow he’d be able to reach someone and let them know that abomination had a weakness. The rebels who stole the plans at Scarif died, but they hoped that they had transmitted the signal in time. Leia hoped the plans would reach the rebels. Hope, Iden. It’s at the root of everything we believe. Without it, we’re nothing.”
>
> “If hope is all you have, then you already are nothing,” Iden said quietly. “And you know what they say. Live in hope…die in despair.”
>
> **She fired.**
> <sub>Battlefront II: Inferno Squad - Chapter 27</sub>

However, it is later said that he was only stunned, so it is likely we will see him again in the future.

> He turned his warm brown eyes back to [Iden]. “When you came back…that night when we left. I saw your blaster as you went up the ramp.” He paused. “**It was on stun.**”
> <sub>Battlefront II: Inferno Squad - Epilogue</sub>

<sup>(all emphasis mine)</sup>